# How to make CheckBox inside InfoWindow true or false

Tags: java, android, google-maps, checkbox, google-maps-markers

I'm using a custom InfoWindowAdapter in order to use my Marker InfoWindow layout, with my data.
Each Marker object has associated an AnimalMarker object (stored in a HashMap)

The Checkboxes however won't update , even though there is no error printed and the Log.d(..) prints the boolean that should be in the checkbox.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or that I'm not aware of regarding CheckBoxes inside InfoWindows?

code inside my MapActivity

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_info_window, null);
                    AnimalMarker animalMarker = allMarkersHashMap.get(marker);
                    if (animalMarker == null) {
                        animalMarker = myMarkersHashMap.get(marker);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "getInfoWindow: animalMarker --> " + animalMarker);

                    TextView miwLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.miwLocation);
                    TextView miwAnimalName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.miwAnimalName);
                    TextView miwAnimalAge = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.miwAnimalAge);
                    ImageView miwImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.miwImage);
                    CheckBox miwAdultCB = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.miwAdultCB);
                    CheckBox miwNeuteredCB = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.miwNeuteredCB);

                    miwLocation.setText(marker.getTitle());
                    miwAnimalName.setText(animalMarker.getAnimal().getAnimalName());
                    miwAnimalAge.setText(animalMarker.getAnimal().getAproxAge().toString() + " yrs");



              miwAdultCB.setChecked(animalMarker.getAnimal().isAdult());
                    Log.d(TAG, "getInfoWindow: made AdultCB = " + animalMarker.getAnimal().isAdult());
              miwNeuteredCB.setChecked(animalMarker.getAnimal().isNeutered());


                    switch (animalMarker.getAnimal().getSpecies()) {
                        case "dog":
                            miwImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog_icon);
                            break;
                        case "cat":
                            miwImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_icon);
                            break;
                        default:
                            miwImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.cat_icon);
                    }

                    return view;
                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

R.layout.marker_info_window :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/white_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miwLocation"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="miwLocation"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/dog_icon"
            android:id="@+id/miwImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/miwLocation"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miwAnimalName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/miwLocation"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/miwImage"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/miwImage"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="miwAnimalName"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/miwAnimalAge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/miwLocation"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/miwAnimalName"
            android:text="3 yrs"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/miwAdultCB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/miwAnimalName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/miwImage"
            android:text=" Adult"
            android:textSize="18dp"

            android:clickable="false"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/miwNeuteredCB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/miwAnimalName"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/miwAdultCB"
            android:text=" Neutered"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:clickable="false"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Images of the layout design and of the resulting InfoWindow:

[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little late but as stated [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#custom_info_windows):

The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.